# Do I use a regular expression on this file path?

Tags: c#

I have to strip a file path and get the parent folder.

Say my path is

```
\\ServerA\FolderA\FolderB\File.jpg
```

I need to get

1. File Name = File.jog
2. Folder it resides in = FolderB
3. And parent folder = FolderA

I always have to go 2 levels up from where the file resides.

Is there an easier way or is a regular expression the way to go?

Comment: I would answer the same as Adam Robinson's, but Jon Skeet's will also do the trick.  I +1'd both of them and either should work for you just fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) is your friend:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"\\ServerA\FolderA\FolderB\File.jpg";
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
        Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);                  // Prints File.jpg
        Console.WriteLine(fi.Directory.Name);        // Prints FolderB
        Console.WriteLine(fi.Directory.Parent.Name); // Prints FolderA
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly why I don't answer C# questions when I think Jon Skeet is around, there's no way to beat him. :-D

Answer (score 6):

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
string parent = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
string parentParent = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(parent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Directory class (better choice than DirectoryInfo in this case).  It does everything you need.  You should not use a regex or any other parsing technique.

Comment: DirectoryInfo is great for getting the folder and parent folder but he also wanted to get the file name.

Comment: Path has a static method to pull off the file name properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
var fi = new FileInfo(@"\\ServerA\FolderA\FolderB\File.jpg");
fi.Name
fi.Directory.Name
fi.Directory.Parent.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that you are always dealing with a file and two directories, try using split:

```
string s = @"\\ServerA\FolderA\FolderB\File.jpg";
string[] parts = s.Split('\'); // might need '\\'
string file = parts[parts.Length];
string parentDir = parts[parts.Length - 1];
string grandParentDir = parts[parts.Length - 2];
```

Comment: There are utility functions that are far less brittle. Don't parse (or construct) path strings yourself. This is also horribly unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to do this actually which use actual .net objects instead of regex.

You can use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx):

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"\\ServerA\FolderA\FolderB\File.jpg");
fileInfo.Name //will give you the file name;
DirectoryInfo directory = fileInfo.Directory; //will give you the parent folder of the file (FolderB);
directory.Parent; //will give you this directories parent folder (FolderA)
```